# функция file.write() удаляет предыдущие значения

Tags: python, файлы

Я делаю код на языке python, парсер в телеграмм. Одна из его функций, приведенная ниже, должна записывать номер телефона, айди и имя пользователя в файл. Однако записывается лишь последний номер, айди и имя, а остальные стираются.

```
        with open('id-numbers.txt','r') as info:
        info.read()
        if a in info:
            pass
        else:
            with io.open('id-numbers.txt', 'w') as info:
                info.write('ID:'+(b)+' | '+'Номер телефона:'+(a)+' | '+'Username:'+(c)+'\n')
```

Выявил, что причина в проверке на отсутствие элемента в файле. Как можно эту проверку исправить, чтобы в файле были все номера итд и повторялись лишь 1 раз?

Comment: `if a not in info` - операция делает не то что вы хотите. Отдельно прочтите файл в память, выполните поиск. Если поиск не успешен, откройте файл на запись (вы сейчас так и делаете) и добавьте новую запись уже без условий.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy сделал, все равно не работает

Comment: Пожалуйста, поместите попытку вашего решения в вопрос. Без кода могу вам только посочувствовать.

Comment: хорошо, сейчас сделаю

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Поместил

Comment: Отдельный `info.read()` уберите. Условие запишите как `if a in info.read():`.

Comment: Верните `'a'` вместо `'w'`.

Answer (score 1):

1. прочитать файл и убедится что такого телефона в нём нет.
2. открыть файл на добавление и записать новую строку.

```
with open('id-numbers.txt', 'r') as info:
    is_in = a in info.read()
if not is_in:
    with open('id-numbers.txt', 'a') as info:
        info.write('ID:'+(b)+' | '+'Номер телефона:'+(a)+' | '+'Username:'+(c)+'\n')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы!